Can't add margin or padding to GridView without overflowing
Im trying to simply add a margin or padding to my GridView. I have the GridView nested within a Flex > Expanded. I have these widgets as I want to prevent doing positioning manually as it leads to these overflowing problems.
Here is my code:
class GetHelp extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetHelp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Flex(
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                color: CustomColors.primaryColor,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                      child: Flex(
                        direction: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 2,
                            child: Text(
                                "XXXXXXXXXX",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                )),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/fox.png',
                              width: 30,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    // Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0)),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: TextField(
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[400]!),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[600]!),
                                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(50))),
                            errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red[600]!),
                            ),
                            focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red[800]!),
                            ),
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                            hintText: "What do you need help with?",
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            filled: true,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              // constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 250),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Need help? Check out our most common categories.",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  GridView.builder(
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: list.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                              mainAxisExtent: 50,
                              crossAxisCount: 2),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ElevatedButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => {},
                            label: Text(
                              list[index].name,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            icon: Icon(
                              list[index].icon.icon,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: list[index].color,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                // side: BorderSide(
                                //     width: 2,
                                //     color:
                                //         const Color.fromARGB(255, 102, 41, 41)),
                              ),
                            ));
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

So when I try to add margin: EdgeInsets.all(15), or padding: EdgeInsets.all(15), to the Container that holds GridView, it overflows.
How do I add margin to this Container without causing overflowing?

Wrap your GridView.builder directly inside an Expanded widget.
This will ensure that the GridView can adjust its size within the available space without overflowing, and you can freely apply margin or padding to the surrounding Container.
Fixed example:
Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: Container(
    // constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 250),
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15), // You can adjust this as needed
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15), // You can adjust this as needed
    child: Column(
      children: [
        const Text(
          "Need help? Check out our most common categories.",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 17,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded( // This is the key to fix the issue
          child: GridView.builder(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: list.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              mainAxisExtent: 50,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => {},
              label: Text(
                list[index].name,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              icon: Icon(
                list[index].icon.icon,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: list[index].color,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  // side: BorderSide(
                  //     width: 2,
                  //     color:
                  //         const Color.fromARGB(255, 102, 41, 41)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)

